Reference request: name for the following topology on probability measures
Given a sequence of probability measures $\mu_n, \mu$ on some measurable space $X$, we say that $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ setwise if, for every measurable $A \subseteq X$, $\mu_n (A) \rightarrow \mu (A)$.
Question: I am wondering if there is a name for the weaker notion of convergence where instead we only require that $\mu_n (A) \rightarrow \mu (A)$ for all open A (in the case where $X$ is Polish).

Since you have tagged the question as 'weak-convergence' I suppose you are familiar with its definition for probability measures and the Portmanteau theorem. $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if $\liminf \mu_n(A) \ge \mu(A)$ for all open sets $A$ of $X$. This is clearly weaker than your condition since if $\mu_n(A) \rightarrow  \mu(A)$ then $\liminf \mu_n(A) = \lim \mu_n(A) = \mu(A) \ge \mu(A)$ and we trivially have weak convergence. The reason for the non-symmetric definition is that we want to captures convergence in a way that's sufficient for integration against continuous functions.

Exactly. So convergence of the measure assigned to opens should be somewhere in between weak and setwise convergence. But I am wondering (a) if this notion of convergence has a name and has been studied directly, and (b) exactly how much stronger a topology than weak convergence one would end up with.
